# Problem with repeating requests in Android application

Tags: android, request, httpurlconnection

We have a problem with repeating requests. Our application (for Android) makes very simple requests to API (Ubuntu + Nginx). We have recently noticed in our logs and the Nginx server logs that very often (even 10% of users which means thousands in ou case) a single call (but not only, because it can also be a group of requests) is often called by the application even tens of thousands of times, it looks e.g. yes:

```
/api/v1/endpoint1 10:00:00
/api/v1/endpoint1 10:00:00
/api/v1/endpoint1 10:00:01
/api/v1/endpoint1 10:00:01
/api/v1/endpoint1 10:00:02
/api/v1/endpoint1 10:00:02
/api/v1/endpoint1 10:00:02
/api/v1/endpoint1 10:00:00
```

(20,000 requests)

We also noticed several groups of requests

```
/api/v1/endpoint1 10:00:00
/api/v1/endpoint2 10:00:00
/api/v1/endpoint3 10:00:01
/api/v1/endpoint1 10:00:01
/api/v1/endpoint2 10:00:02
/api/v1/endpoint3 10:00:02
/api/v1/endpoint1 10:00:02
/api/v1/endpoint2 10:00:00
/api/v1/endpoint3 10:00:00
```

It happens tens of thousands of times in a row or only 50 (but also in a row). It affects normal requests made by URLConnection.

In most cases, everything works fine - we make, for example, one request to display the results list so only one request is made. Also, on our test devices we were not able to reproduce it, everything works correctly (so one request). We would be very grateful for any suggestions and ideas how to sort it out because we seem to be at a dead end.

The problem occurs on various devices of different manufacturers, from Adnroid 4 to 9.

Code from activity (cleaned of unnecessary things):

```
private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
...
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    changeButton = (Button) findInLayout(R.id.changeButton);
    changeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String data1 = data1edit.getText().toString();
            final String data2 = data2edit.getText().toString();
            executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    boolean isSuccess = false;
                    HttpURLConnection conn;
                    try {
                        conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(MY_API_URL).openConnection();
                        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                        // setup headers, timeouts etc...
                        conn.setDoOutput(true);
                        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
                        writer.write(... some post data ...);
                        writer.close();
                        conn.connect();
                        isSuccess = conn.getResponseCode() == 200;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        if (conn != null) {
                            conn.disconnect();
                        }
                    }

                    if (isSuccess) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // show toast with success message + update ui
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // show toast with error message + update ui
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

Request log screen:
[image: Request log]

Comment: Are you sure the multiple requests aren't related. For example, when you send a request, the HTTP client might first send an HTTP OPTIONS request to just send the headers of what it is asking for so the server can verify it can accept the request, for things like CORS, then if the server responds 200 OK to the OPTIONS request, the HTTP client will then send the normal HTTP POST/GET request as expected?